# Добавить команду в командный интерфейс формы элемента справочника

Tags: 1с

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста.

**Вопрос:
Как добавить свою команду в командный интерфейс формы элемента справочника ? Мне надо это сделать программно.**

Конфа: Управление медицинским центром (2.0.43.2)

1С:Предприятие 8.3 (8.3.16.1148)

В конфе есть группа команд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К этой группе команд привязаны общие команды, они определены в конфе, а также указано для какого справочника предназначены
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В форме справочника на вкладке командный интерфейс они видны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форме пишу код, он отрабатывает без ошибок, но почему-то на форму кнопку не добавляет. В отладчике видно, что кнопка добавилась в подчиненные элементы группы "ИнформацияОКлиенте". В настройка формы, моей команды нет.

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ПриСозданииНаСервере(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    // Создадим команду
    Команда     = ЭтаФорма.Команды.Добавить("МояКоманда");
    Команда.Действие    = "ОбработчикМоейКоманды";

    // Создадим кнопку и привяжем к ней команду
    Кнопка      = ЭтаФорма.Элементы.Добавить("ВыполнитьМоюКоманду", Тип("КнопкаФормы"), 
                      ЭтаФорма.Элементы.ФормаИнформацияОКлиенте);
    Кнопка.Заголовок    = "Выполнить мою команду";
    Кнопка.ИмяКоманды   = "МояКоманда";
    Кнопка.Вид    = ВидКнопкиФормы.КнопкаКоманднойПанели;
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОбработчикМоейКоманды(Команда)
    Сообщить(4444444);
КонецПроцедуры
```

В результате в группе команд, моей команды нет, кто-нибудь знает в чем проблема и как это победить ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]